# select multiple bones from different armatures

Tags: animation, bones, selection-tools

Is there a way to select multiple bones not belonging to the same armature? And to create selection sets with bones from different armatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: You can in 2.8, to do so you need to disable the *Lock Object Modes* option.

Edit: About your second question, I quote you: "You can select bones from different armatures and then add them at the same selection set. Although unfortunately the selection set will only be visible in one of the armatures and not in all of them"

[image]

Comment: that's great, thanks for your answer! It worked!

And thanks to this, it turns out that you can select bones from different armatures and then add them at the same selection set. Although unfortunately the selection set will only be visible in one of the armatures and not in all of them, for some reason.

But at least it works :)

Comment: oh ok I didn't know that  ;)